# How quickly could a "shapeshifter" lose mass, realistically?

Tags: internal-consistency, biology, shapeshifters

Shapeshifters and mass... ever the bane of realistic science fiction.

#### Basics:

Let's say someone is changing shape (for whatever reason, voluntary or involuntary, it doesn't matter for this purpose). Don't worry about what is *causing* this to happen. Let's also say that the start and end forms have non-trivially different size (mass).

[Is there a credible way a shapeshifter could gain/lose body mass when changing forms?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/449) asks about some *ways* that this can happen. The unfortunate reality, as noted in some of the answers there, is that if we want to stick to the realm of biological plausibility (which I want to do), the sort of "Hollywood" shapeshifting that happens in a matter of seconds or minutes is simply not possible. Realistic shapeshifting takes months, or even years... right?

Rather than asking *how* it can happen, I'd like to ask how *quickly* it can happen. I expect "days" (at least as a single-digit number) is right out, but what *is* a plausible duration?

#### Details:

Let's also assume that the body of the "shifter" (victim? Er... let's just call her "[Alice](/questions/171644)") isn't changing radically, so we're not worried about having to replace functioning organs with completely different ones. This gives us a nice cop-out for *increasing* mass; we can look at growth rates of real critters and use that as a reference, maybe with a little bit of fudge factor because we're bending the rules a bit as to how this is being triggered in the first place. What about *decreasing* mass?

I can think of three possibilities:

- The body "eats" itself in a carefully controlled manner such that everything is being constantly put back together, only smaller. Mass that isn't needed is expelled through "usual" mechanisms (sweat, shedding, urination, defecation).
- The body uses the resources of the outer parts to grow a new body inside of the old one, which is then cast off in a much squickier version of reptile shedding.
- The body liquefies everything but the most critical bits and grows a new body from the resulting soup.

The last is both the most and least plausible; similar to how eggs and cocoons work (indeed, for my purposes, plenty of insects are shapeshifters to a greater degree than I need), but seems dubious without some sort of protective shell. The second seems like it would have issues with the skeleton. I lean toward the first for several reasons:

- Alice is plausibly motile (if clumsy) for the entire duration.
- Alice isn't starting from scratch as far as motor control; the skeleton, muscles and nerves are all in the same configuration. (Again, some clumsiness expected due to the size change, but this is basically the process we all go through growing up, only backwards.)
- Lost mass is dealt with in a gradual manner via ordinary mechanisms, rather than all at once in a great big mess.

In addition:

- Alice is able (but not required) to <strike>eat</strike> take in nourishment during this process at a rate of up to 3,000 calories / day, in addition to what her body can get from "eating itself". Anything extra is shed or excreted.
- The transformation process is allowed to (and almost certainly *must*) "overdrive" Alice's normal healing ability, but not "magically" so (less "Wolverine"/"Deadpool", more "young child"). For the purposes of the transformation, cancer is a non-issue.
- Aside from whatever triggered the transformation (which may be external!), Alice's biology is otherwise normal. Answers requiring exotic organs or the like must include the time to grow those organs in the first place. (I'll allow them to be "left over" at the end, but really, avoiding this sort of thing is preferred.)

#### Summary:

So... is this at least *somewhat* plausible, and if so, how quickly could a process like this occur? (My goal is for Alice to lose about 60% of her initial mass in about a month, but answers that can be generalized/extrapolated are better for the community.) Again, I'm [hand-waving](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AWizardDidIt) *why* this is happening, but I'd like to keep rest of the mechanics fairly grounded in plausible biology.

Comment: What is Alice turning into?

Comment: Losing weight is really easy for humans (active humans), actually it's mechanically way  harder to gain mass than losing it.... Fortunately alice is a shapeshifer, she's no human so she can be even faster. Just look at real life shapeshifter like eggs, butterflies and other wormy things like maggots. Some animals have special ways to lose instantly mass,  crabs can amputate their own limbs, snails can cut themselves in half, worms too... And lizards can amputate their own tails.  But I guess even a normal person could amputate her own limbs if she really needed to lose weight desperately.

Comment: @Halfthawed, answers that don't need to know that preferred. That said, I did specify that "we're not worried about having to replace functioning organs with completely different ones." The best case would be "a younger version of herself", but I think it shouldn't matter as long as no major changes need to happen.

Comment: @Kyu, I'm not asking about just "losing weight", I'm asking about transforming, shapeshifter-style, from one form to another, smaller *but still fully functional* form. That means things like bones and organs (and limbs) need to get *smaller*, not just get lopped off. (At best, you're talking about my "option 2".)

Comment: Well it depends on what is she gonna do with all the excess energy... If it doesn't become fat because she is losing weight and transforming, then she needs a reason for why she isn't just shedding off the excess weight.... 1kg  of human weight(tissue) is  MORE  than enough to keep you running non stop for 24 hours.... Is she a runner?

Comment: I guess you could make the shapeshifting mechanism really inefficient and make it waste a lot of energy for nothing.... Maybe she needs to reach an incredible temperature during the transformation.  Between a normal human can lose between  0 to 1.6 kilograms a day or even more depending on how food deprived and active they are. There are people who can run for days, and humans survive without food for quite a lot of time, so we are really good at losing weight.

Comment: @Kyu, I'm pretty sure rebuilding a body isn't a trivial amount of work, but yes, any extra *is* just being cast off (ahem: "sweat, shedding, urination, defecation", or something squickier). Preferably not in large chunks. Again, I'm not talking about transforming from a healthy adult into a malnourished concentration camp survivor, but (as an example) from a healthy adult *human* into a healthy adult *wolf*. Or a healthy *child*.

Comment: @Matthew The first option sounds the most efficient for a gradual change, what are the limits to how fast their body can repair?

Comment: @RandySavage, that sounds like a plausible restatement of the problem; not sure that was your intent? 

Comment: To whoever voted to close, please be a good citizen and explain *what* you think needs to be clarified...

Comment: @Matthew There was a similar question which left me with axolotls and whale calves on my mind for the speed of biological growth lol, if you can justify how waste leaves the body fast and safely and major changes could be done during sleep, then the speed of growing the smaller organs or shaping them down could be the biggest factor.

Answer (score 5):

This isn't an answer to the question as asked, but since I mentioned:

> We can look at growth rates of real critters and use that as a reference, maybe with a little bit of fudge factor because we're bending the rules a bit as to how this is being triggered in the first place.

I thought I'd follow up on that. (Also, thanks to [RandySavage](/users/69935) for hinting to look at whales!)

Okay, so... *gaining* mass?

Well, cattle go from ~85 lbs to ~1200 lbs in 18 months ([source](https://www.drovers.com/article/beeftalk-2-pounds-average-daily-gain-equals-grass-beef)); an increase of roughly 14 times birth weight. The growth rate of blue whales "is likely one of the fastest in the animal world", starting at almost 9,000 lbs and gaining up to 200 lbs per day ([source](https://www.treehugger.com/animals/11-facts-about-blue-whales-largest-animals-ever-known-earth.html)).

Doing some back-of-the-napkin math suggests that doubling in mass in a month is pretty plausible, even for normal animals under normal conditions. Keep in mind we're talking about *functional* mass here, not just fat reserves; that is, it seems plausible for a shapeshifter to *realistically* transform from a Golden Retriever (~70 lbs) to a Great Dane (~140 lbs) in a month, while going from Mountain Lion (~180 lbs) to East African Lion (~380 lbs) is getting near the edge of plausibility. (Obviously, this assumes an adequate food supply! Note also that I've chosen forms that are very similar aside from size; having to do more internal shifting-around is probably going to cut into how quickly a shifter can accomplish changes in mass.)

Being able to *functionally* incorporate mass faster than that (i.e. incorporate it into the skeleton, especially, as well as muscles and organs) probably starts getting into hand-waving territory, which we're trying to avoid.

Comment: Thats a good example using cattle to get your growth speed, are you asking if growth could be faster than this using known biological processes?

Comment: Not really. My specific case is interested in *decreasing* mass, anyway, and that's the case that can't (as I show here) be trivially answered by looking at real growth rates. Since I mentioned in the question that giving a rate for *increased* mass can be done fairly easily by looking at actual animal growth rates, I figured I'd follow up by actually providing that answer rather than leaving it as an exercise for the reader. That said, answers explaining why the above is conservative are welcome in the hopes of helping others, but don't address my immediate issue.

Comment: I am wondering if a brain can be shrunk down to 40% size but still function the same?

Comment: Well, for the case of an adult shifting to a child ([ahem](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Rascals_(episode)) ), [Willk](/users/31698) [says](/a/175727/43697) there's no issue. For other cases, there's https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/3108. However, I consider that off-topic for this question.

Comment: I'm not sure how relevant this is but the immortal jellyfish is coming to mind especially when it reverts back to an immature stage by recycling its old cells "transdifferentiation" , https://allthatsinteresting.com/immortal-jellyfish

Answer (score 0):

Your shapeshifter is absorbing (reabsorbing perhaps) exotic weakly interacting particles that for the most part are always floating around him/her through a process that converts them into straight up baryons. (This isn't very plausible given the Standard Model though). These particles might not even have mass in the strict sense, until converted, and thus would be difficult to detect (but this isn't a requirement if there's only a few thousand pounds/tons of them in the immediate vicinity).

There would be an organ or organs located internally that does this, and it probably spits out wholly formed cells. This process is also exothermic, so that the shapeshifter's biology should be able to tolerate a large amount of heat being dumped into it. The cells don't need to be capable of division, so maybe they don't even have nuclei (like mammalian red blood cells).

Through a similar process, mass can be unconverted back into the weakly interacting particles at will. This might or might not use the same organs for that process.

To explain why this "dark matter" is always close to the shapeshifter, we either have to posit that it exists everywhere in more or less equal proportion, or that its attracted to them via some unknown physical force. Since we're already creating novel particles, that's only slightly more implausible than the rest.

This would allow for rapid shape-changing, something on par with the Incredible Hulk.

Comment: Uh... no. There's a reason I added [tag:reality-check]. I'm only hand-waving *why* Alice's body is doing this. For the *how*, please try to stick to real physics/biology. When your answer even *says* things like "this isn't very plausible given the Standard Model though", that should be a tip-off that your answer probably isn't compatible with [tag:reality-check].

Comment: @Matthew reality is that nothing like a shapeshifter is possible. That's not a helpful answer though. It wasn't marked hard-science, my answer's good even if it doesn't appeal to you.

Comment: Depending on your definition, butterflies (in fact, many of insects) beg to differ. If we go loose enough, *you* are a shapeshifter; you have changed shape quite a bit from when you were born. RandySavage even mentioned an organism that *does* revert to an earlier life stage. *Slow* shapeshifting (months) *is* at least somewhat plausible. What isn't is shapeshifters like we see in media that can change form in seconds or minutes. The whole point is that I am explicitly *not* asking about that variety. Accordingly, answers that try to justify "Hollywood shapeshifting" aren't really on topic.

Comment: @Matthew Should I vote to close your question because you worded it poorly then? You're not asking for shapeshifters at all in any sense that anyone else would mean. You're just asking for organisms that develop into different shapes, which is pretty much every organism ever.

Comment: How is it worded poorly? I thought I clearly indicated that I am talking about "shifters" (note the quotes, also in the subject) that operate in a manner that is actually plausible. That is, in fact, the *entire premise of the question*. Maybe you are confused because I asked "If an organism changes shape in a *realistic* manner, *how quickly* can it do so?". You seem to have answered "If an organism changes shape in a *quick* manner, how can it *realistically* do so?". Okay, so the difference is "only" a couple words in different order, but in *meaning* those are very different.

Comment: @Matthew But that's not a "shifter" at all. It's just an organism that grows, which all do. And "plausibility" isn't as strict as you make it out to be. There very well may be undiscovered particles not currently understood to fit with the Standard Model. The trouble here is that you already had an idea of what kind of answer you wanted, but didn't like mine because it doesn't validate your preconceived notions. I'm not confused, you're just bad at English.

Comment: @Matthew "I want a shapeshifter and by that I mean something not commonly understood to be a shapeshifter at all, but just an organism that grows into highly dissimilar forms over a period of months/years as all of them do". Your answer is provided by Richard Simmons, who once helped an 900 lb man shed over 350 pounds in a period of a year. I do not know of any other example where more mass was lost more quickly in a "realistic" scenario.

Comment: "you already had an idea of what kind of answer you wanted"... and as I understand it, that's sort of *the point* of [tag:reality-check]. Your answer goes off in a completely different direction which even the original version of the question suggests to avoid. (BTW, that idea of what kind of answer you wanted" is in the original; did you read it?) It's not my fault you insist on switching my axiom (realism) with my unknown (speed).