# Energy manipulating superhero -- how would it work

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, physics, energy, super-powers

I want to make a superhero that can control all forms of energy. From what I've heard you can do a lot like, manipulate time and space, open blackholes, teleport, shape shift, and manipulate matter. Doctor solar can do those things and he can also turn invisible, phase through solid matter and alter realities, how can he do those things?

What I'm interested in is a scientific explanation of these powers and/or other ways energy manipulation can be utilized for various effects. Including all forms of energy.

Comment: Scientific explanation of magical powers, which ignore laws or science as we understand them currently, or with no known scientific explanation? That would be few Nobel Prizes right there. Will you share the prize?

Comment: i just want an idea, how can you utilize energy?

Comment: Or how can i learn about energy so that I can use that knowledge for my story

Comment: If you want to learn, start by reading Wikipedia and HowStuffWorks.

Comment: If you add the word "pseudo" before science, maybe someone can suggest things.  But science can't explain any of those as most of them are not possible in our universe.

Comment: Do you require FTL teleportation, or not? That is, would [quantum teleportation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_teleportation) be permissible?

Comment: Doctor Solar my favorite also Super President the animated series. :)

Comment: i just want fictional answers if thats possible. like this     http://www.magnetowasright.com/pages/analysis/the-science-of-magneto.php  http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3998/is-magnetos-power-magnetism-or-can-he-manipulate-all-metals

Answer (score 9):

**Here's what your guy would have to do:**

> manipulate time and space

Well, actually, we all do this, because we all have mass and therefore all exert a gravitational force. But to manipulate things *at will*, he'll either have to:

1. *Create new mass and/or energy at a given point.* We've had questions similar to this before; unfortunately, I can't find any at the moment. But he'd essentially have to go against the law of conservation of mass/energy to do this, so this approach is a big no-no.
2. *Manipulate the [universal scale factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale_factor_(cosmology)).* Doing this would change the expansion/contraction/overall evolution of the universe. This is also patently impossible.

> open blackholes

To do this, he'll have to compress a chunk of matter into an area smaller than the matter's Schwarzschild radius. The process is possible, and it happens during supernovae. However, I highly doubt that a human - no matter what *realistic* powers s/he may have - would be capable of such a feat.

> teleport

Now we're breaking special relativity, too! Moving from one place to another instantaneously is *also* impossible, because you'd be going faster - a lot faster - than $c$. There are many iffy solutions to this, such as using wormholes, but at the moment, they're entirely theoretical. You also have the risk that the wormhole would close up before you can enter it - and this indeed happens in some wormhole solutions.

> shape shift

We've had some related questions here, such as [this one](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/449/is-there-a-credible-way-a-shapeshifter-could-gain-lose-body-mass-when-changing-f). Possible solutions suggested included exchanging matter with the shapeshifter's surroundings, changing the density of the shapeshifter, and (my favorite) having the shapeshifter me composed of tiny nanobots, which can easily change from one form the another. Choose at will.

> manipulate matter

You're going to have to be more specific on this one. Technically, we're constantly manipulating matter.

> turn invisible

Easy. Deflect the light around him. You could do this via gravitational lensing by putting two black holes (or other sufficiently massive objects) on either side of him, so the light is bent away. This has the disadvantage of being a) Implausible and b) Deadly. He'll be stretched to smithereens within seconds.

> through solid matter

I seem to recall a question on Physics about this. He'd have to overcome the electric force from the protons and electrons inside the matter, which would be incredibly hard. He'd also have to manage to disassemble himself to fit through any "gaps" between atoms/molecule. I'd say that - once again - this is scientifically impossible.

> alter realities

I have no idea what you're talking about here.

---

Not to burst your bubble, but all of these things are absolutely impossible.

Comment: "Teleport" need not imply instantaneous teleportation, it could just be at the speed of light or close to it, which is possible in principle with "quantum teleportation", which requires transmission of information via a "classical channel" like light signals. And another way to "manipulate gravity" might be to locally alter the gravitational constant--physicist Kip Thorne suggests something like this might be possible in theories of [large extra dimensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_extra_dimension) in his book *The Science of Interstellar*.

Comment: @Hypnosifl Ah, I completely forgot about quantum teleportation! I had been interpreting the skill as instantaneous teleportation, though, so I suppose that would be invalid. But I'll check. Didn't know about altering the gravitational constant.

Comment: so how are these things possible within energy manipulation? And also are there any way you can utilize energy fictionally. I know this is a lot guys and I truly appreciate the help. But its just a story, i know its not possible i want to know how my character can utilize energy manipulation.

Comment: http://powerlisting.wikia.com/wiki/Energy_Manipulation   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vulcan_(Marvel_Comics)       now these should give you some examples of what Im trying to do.

Comment: @AaronTuturro, your questions in the previous comment are ill-formed. I think you are looking for: plausible to the reader within the universe of the story. You want to know what kimd of alternate physical law would make for a good story. That is broad and can be "anything".

Comment: what do you mean anything? sorry for the mixup, but i don't want real answers just fictional answers to this subject.

Comment: @AaronTuturro - Basically, you have two contradictory requirements: You want full-blown high-powered energy manipulation, which (as this answer shows) contravenes a large number of fundamental laws, *and* you want it based on science.  **You can't have both**.  Your choices are to **A)** rewrite the question such that you're asking for a supertech/magic based answer (and remove the `reality-check` and `physics` tags), or to **B)** rewrite the question such that you're asking which of these powers are possible within known science (even if we don't have a mechanism to do them).

Comment: This is an awesome line-up +1 to you AND the question, because everybody likes people's answers to my questions, but not the questions themselves. But you forget quantum mechanics as far as teleportation.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like we're in The Matrix and he has admin rights. Virtual reality in general, allows someone to "alter reality" by manipulating the next level up.

Comment: This is a reasonable supposition- there is a good chance that the universe is a simulation ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulation_hypothesis ) so if someone was going to have these impossible abilities, the ability to exploit a simulated reality would explain that.  Of course, this was the whole idea that _The Matrix_ was based on - an attempt to create a superhero that made sense.

Comment: This is perfect. +1

Answer (score 2):

Let's take a walk through poorly adapted interpretations of high level physics.

String theory is probably the closest thing we have right now to a "theory of everything". It holds that all fundamental particles can be modeled mathematically as a string that vibrates in a wave that describes its interactions with the fundamental forces of the universe. One form of the theory, called Bosonic string theory, models all particles except the theoretical tachyon as a set of forces vibrating in 26 dimensions. That's science - the rest of this is pretty much not.

First, this depends on these vibrations being completely real, rather than a mathematical model - this may or may not be the case. But, if it is, and if he could sense and control these vibrations, in real time, he could make absolutely anything happen, without exception.

Everything involves strings at some level. Invisibility? Flat line the vibrations of the photons bouncing off of you. Teleportation would only be limited to the range in which our subject could make a copy of himself using strings that are at the target area. Walk through walls? Make them incorporeal. Fly? Turn gravity off. Black hole? Convert all incoming light from all sources into solid matter for a while and then force it into a singularity.

Note that energy still cannot be created nor destroyed, so adding or removing complexity to these strings will take something from the character. He will have to learn to get that back before it kills him. Fortunately, he will have a readily available source of energy - he could flat line the strings of the immaterial dark energy the planet is (probably) completely awash in. If any of this is possible at all, he could also convert any ordinary matter to energy as a matter of course.

It is important to note, that for any of this to have any viable interpretation at all, our subject essentially has telekinesis - and not only that, he has super-subatomic remote viewing, and his brain has to be more effective than a server farm to use it effectively.

Comment: You just explained how to do LITERALLY ANYTHING. That is beyond awesome.

Answer (score 0):

You might like to chek out super man's science you might not know but his most powers like heat vision,solar flare etc come from sun.
This can be given like when he absorbs energy his cell get charged
The one that you want i.e. Manipulation of space time 
According to einstine's theory the space time acts as a single fabric and when any thing with mass interacts with it it wraps and bends space time around if you want to do at will , the fictional science can be given that die to certai inter dimentional force feild helps him control gravitons and higsbozone one is theoratical and higs has been proven of existance they are responsible for gravitationa l force and mass respectively
This will solve for time travel , space time manipulation as well as flight. You might like to check explanation on you tube for superman's flight and theory of relativity.
For a fact you think sun is no good source only 15 min of energy coming from sun can fulfill the need of whole world for a whole year.
If you store enough energy and are able to use it by vibrating your body molecule at rigt frequency you can phase or pass through object. Flash science . I would like to tell you that i've been searching for all this for long and working on same may be we can share our ideas.
My own thinking. It would be best if the character can absorbe energy from multiple source this way he would be indistructible. If you want some enemy to cope wothis can be psyche.also a great fact unlike any othe speedster he can absorb thr force made by friction of air as well as when he runs at speed faster than light then particles wont produce frictoin but you will become a running fusion reactor and would need no extra energy as you would absorb the same energy you produce.also fusion reactor produce great amount of it.

Comment: This is a solid "block" answer. "Blocks" this large make the text hard to read. Try and separate your answers into "paragraphs" three or four sentences large. From what I read, this also seems...like gibberish to be polite. Perhaps you could refactor this answer into something more intelligible? Thanks in advance.